# IIS7 and SSL certificates

Tags: iis-7, ssl-certificate

I have several IIS servers and several Apache servers. When I created the CSR and obtained my "star" certificate, I built the CSR on my Apache server.
I obtained the certificate from Digicert and got a file with .CRT files in them.

Can I use these on my IIS servers?

Or do I have to create a CSR for EACH server and then get a new cert for each server?

Comment: Take a look at this solution:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9971464/install-crt-certificate-on-iis-7-5

Comment: post as answer and you get the points

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9971464/install-crt-certificate-on-iis-7-5 which uses OpenSSL's pkcs12 command to convert a crt file into a pfx

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can combine the certificate from Digicert with the private key that you have when you generated the certificate.  I would use openSSL to do it.

It will look something like this:
openssl pkcs12 -export -out IIS.pfx -inkey client.key -in client.crt

You can then install the certificate on the computer that has IIS in the local certificate store for that computer and select it via IIS.